# Define a curried anonymous function

Tags: function-construction, functional-style

I want to define a function like

```
f[x_][y_][z_] := x + 2y + 3z
```

but anonymously. The ways to do this that I've discovered so far are

(1) define a normal function first, then curry it:

```
f = Function[{x,y,z}, x + 2y + 3z] // Curry[#,3]&
```

(2) define the function in λ-calculus style:

```
f = Function[x, Function[y, Function[z, x + 2y + 3z]]]
```

However, none of these look good. Is there a way to define an anonymous function `f` in its curried form directly? Something like

```
f = CurriedFunction[{x,y,z}, x + 2y + 3z]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think I found a way to do it nicely:

```
f = x |-> y |-> z |-> x + 2 y + 3 z
```

It looks nicer in the front end:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
SetAttributes[CurriedFunction, HoldAll];
CurriedFunction[vars_, body_] := 
  If[VectorQ[vars] && Length[vars] > 0,
   Block[vars,
    Fold[Function[#2, #1] &, Function[Evaluate[vars[[-1]]], body], 
     Rest[Reverse[vars]]]
    ],
   Function[vars, body]
   ];

x = 7;
y = 8;
z = 9;
f = CurriedFunction[{x, y, z}, 1 + 1 + x + 2 y + 3 z]
f[x][y][z]
```

> Function[x, Function[y, Function[z, 1 + 1 + x + 2 y + 3 z]]]
>
> 50

Comment: Thanks Henrik. If I want to *define* `CurriedFunction`, then I can simply do `CurriedFunction[vars_, body_] := Curry[Function[Evaluate@vars, body], Length[vars]]`; that's clear. I'm more looking for a builtin functionality.